# How can I safely render HTML content from a WYSIWYG editor in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

What is the best practice for safely encoding output of content that was created using a WYSIWYG editor in ASP.NET/MVC5? I would like tags related to formatting and layout etc. to render as HTML but at the same time avoid XSS attacks. The editor is Summernote, not that this should matter.

Obviously, this is highly insecure:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Content);
```

This is completely wrong:

```
@Model.Content
```

And the Microsoft Sanitizer goes too far the other way, removing almost all formatting that was added with the WYSIWYG editor.

```
@Html.Raw(Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(Model.Content))
```

Is there another built-in or popular library that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no "best practice" for doing this. You're fighting the framework. MVC is designed to render a model (a bag a properties) into a view (a template).

In theory, you might be able to strip out all the content from your WYSIWYG output that is derived from user input (i.e. the stuff that might cause XSS and SQL injection), sanitize the pieces, and put them back in. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I can see your point about fighting the framework but I want admin users to be able to edit page content and it seems like using a WYSIWYG editor is the simplest way.